# Details on the solution form ridge regression scikit learn needed

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using ridge regression using scikit learn and have made a little test for the penalty parameter.

My question does not seem to depend on my code but might be more general regarding the scikit ridge method - as I simply implement the basic `ridge` regression on some data using:

```python
# [m,y are previously defined from the data I am using.]
    alphas=[1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1,0.5, 1]
    for alpha in alphas:
        model=sklearn.linear_model.Ridge(alpha, positive=true)
        model.fit(m,y);
        r_sq = model.score(m,y);
```

I store the results for every run and I am interested in the resulting `R2` for different penalty values.

Problem: I obtain exactly similar `R2`, regardless of the penalty parameter. The only `alpha` values that I get a different fit and different regression weights are for `alpha=100` and `alpha=10^-12`.

I would expect an `alpha` value of `100` to draw all coefficients to 0 - which is not the case at all.

Doing the same using `lasso`, I get what I would expect: for high values of the penalty parameter, I obtain 0 for all regression weights.

Does anyone know what might be going on within `ridge` `R2`? I read in a blog post that I lost that the penalty parameter is divided by the number of samples, but cannot find this in the scikit method.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop you always overwrite the last result?

You must append the results somehow:

```
r_sq = []
# [m,y are previously defined from the data I am using.]
    alphas=[1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1,0.5, 1]
    for alpha in alphas:
        model=sklearn.linear_model.Ridge(alpha, positive=true)
        model.fit(m,y);
        r_sq_result = model.score(m,y)
        r_sq = r_sq.append(r_sq_result)
```